# Sum to infinity of geometric sequence

Tags: c++, recursion, series, factorial

Question:

> Write C++ function to evaluate the following formula for a given `x`:
>
> [image: function to be evaluated]

The following code was designed in C++ on Visual Studio to be a solution of the above mentioned problem. However whenever I run the code what I am returned is the value of `x`; or the same value I input.

I don't understand what the problem may be, so I would appreciate any help given.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    }
}

unsigned long f(int x, int n) {
    static unsigned long  term;
    static unsigned long sum = 0;
    do {
        term = pow(x, (2 * n + 1)) / fact((2 * n) + 1);
        n++;
        sum += term;
    } while (term < 0.000001);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int y = 0;
    int x;
    cout << "enter x" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << f(x, y) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Check your do-while loop.  On the first run through the loop, what is the value of n, and what is the value of `term`?  Does `term` satisfy the condition to continue the loop?

Comment: Use doubles for term and sum

Comment: @JackC. The condition was indeed reversed and should've been bigger than rather than smaller than! This was a big help!

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux This too fixed it ! I'm not sure why but this made everything run perfectly, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't calculate powers and factorials on each iteration. Each next `term` can be generated by multiplying the previous one by `x^2 / [n(n+1)]`:

```
double sinh_in_disguise(const double x) {
    const double x_sq = x * x;
    double term = x;
    double sum = 0;
    double n = 2;

    while (true) {
        const double new_sum = sum + term;
        if (new_sum == sum)
            break;
        sum = new_sum;
        term *= x_sq / (n * (n + 1));
        n += 2;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(16);
    double x = 2.019;
    std::cout << sinh_in_disguise(x) << std::endl;  // prints 3.699001094869803
    std::cout << std::sinh(x) << std::endl;         // prints 3.699001094869803
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put double datatype in the whole code and it will work perfectly

Comment: Could you provide the working example of your solution in code aswell?